# Can TestNG run multiple suites?

Tags: selenium, testng

I am testing a web-ui using Selenium and TestNG. I have a test suite with many test classes in it. 
I have a `@BeforeSuite` method which also has a `@Parameters` annotation, this method receives as a parameter the **browser** in which the Selenium test will be run, executing the lines:

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, browser, "http://localhost:8099");
selenium.start();
```

The XML I'm using to run the test suite is:

```
<suite name="suite">
<parameter name = "browser" value = "*firefox"/>
 <test name="allTests">
  <classes>
   <class name="test.webui.MemcachedDeploymentTest" />
  </classes>
 </test> 
</suite>
```

This works fine and the test runs in Firefox.
my problem is that i would like to somehow run this suite again, immediately after the first run finishes, but this time with Chrome as the browser. i now have 2 XML suites, one with Chrome and one with Firefox. Is there any way to run these test suites one after the other automatically? maybe using a third XML?

Comment: yes, TestNG can run multiple suites

Answer (score 30):

You can runt testNG suites like this:

```
<suite name="allSuites">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="suite1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="suite2.xml" />
    ...
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

You can also run those suites in parallel with an ant task. If you want I ll provide example code for ant.

Comment: Could you please provide example code for running this in parallel with a maven task?

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried that yet so I cannot provide code for that.

Comment: Tarken, could you "provide example code for ant"?

Comment: Any news on this? i like to run multiple suites defined like this snippet however parrale tag at <suite> not working in any way

Answer (score 15):

To Run Multiple suites using TestNG XML the correct code goes below, Where I have prepared Three suites **`suiteA.xml`**, **`suiteB.xml`**, **`suiteC.xml`** and have consolidated them in **`testng.xml`**. You can copy paste the below code and change the `packagename.classname` in the class tag and run it would work...

**suiteA.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="SuiteA"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 
                 <test name="TestA1" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>
                 <test name="TestA2" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>
    </suite>
```

**suiteB.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="SuiteB"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 
                 <test name="TestB1" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>
                 <test name="TestB2" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB2" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>
</suite>
```

**suiteC.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
        <suite name="SuiteC"  > 
        <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 
                     <test name="TestC1" allow-return-values="true">
                             <classes>
                               <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                     <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteC.TestCaseC1" />
                             </classes>
                     </test>
                     <test name="TestC2" allow-return-values="true">
                             <classes>
                               <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                     <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteC.TestCaseC2" />
                             </classes>
                     </test>
        </suite>
```

**testng.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="TestNG Dadadriver suite"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 
            <suite-files>
                   <suite-file path="./suiteA.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./suiteB.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./suiteC.xml" />
            </suite-files>
    </suite>
```

Comment: Where would ideally the `suiteA.xml, suiteB.xml...` resides  ? Do we need to create a separate folder and copied those xml file ?

Comment: @soccerway : You can specify the path of suite.xml file in <suite-file> tag from where you want to read your suiteA.xml file.

Comment: Thanks Arpan....I have tried your solution...this is working fine. Upvote your answer too.

Comment: Now I have another problem where Safari browser is not identifying a button, my question..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58871378/safari-browser-is-not-identifying-the-button-based-on-cssselector-or-xpath

Comment: is there a way to run the suites in parallel in the above file testng.xml

Comment: Did anyone try to run the same configuration through maven surefire plugin like this clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml. For me, it's giving error. Any lead will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @AnkurSingh : It did work for me using maven..             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: Is there a way to use enable/disable flag for additional control in <suite-file path ... itself />.? Objective is to enable/disable suite-files from a single location of root/master suite testng.xml file

Comment: Can we add listeners to this suite file where all the suites are declared. If yes then how? I know we can add individually for each suite but it throws warning that listeners are displayed multiple time (I don't care about the warning) but some actions are copied twice in the screenshots, how to avoid that?

Answer (score 10):

Put your parameter tag inside the test tag and create another test tag:

```xml
<suite name="suite">
    <test name="Firefox tests">
        <parameter name="browser" value="*firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="test.webui.MemcachedDeploymentTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Chrome tests">
        <parameter name="browser" value="*chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="test.webui.MemcachedDeploymentTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Another option that would be less verbose would be to use `@Factory`.

Comment: here you put the paramater tag in the test tag, i need the parameter to be injected in a @BeforeSuite method, not @BeforeTest

Comment: is there any way on running the same suite twice, each time with a different parameter?

Comment: Yes, use a @Factory and create two instances of your test class, each with a different parameter. Store that parameter in a field and use that field in your test methods. Read the Javadoc for @Factory for more details.

Comment: What if the suites are very big (do not fit in the same file), and still I'd like to run them sequentially? Can a 'master' XML file be used?

Comment: Yes, look up the <suite-files> tag in the testng.xml documentation.

Answer (score 8):

```
<suite name="allSuites">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="suite1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="suite2.xml" />
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Works fine !! It will execute the current suit first and then it will execute the included list of suites one by one.

Comment: Is there a way to use enable/disable flag for additional control in <suite-file path ... itself />.? Objective is to enable/disable suite-files from a single location of root/master suite testng.xml file

Comment: Can we add listeners to this suite file where all the suites are declared. If yes then how? I know we can add individually for each suite but it throws warning that listeners are displayed multiple time (I don't care about the warning) but some actions are copied twice in the screenshots, how to avoid that?

Answer (score 4):

via Maven:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
         <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/unit-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
         <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/api-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```