# Safari browser is not identifying the button based on cssSelector or xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safari

My tests are Failing while running the in the Safari browser pointed to `Browserstack` cloud env.
Could anyone please advise on how to fix the problem here. When a button is clicked, system displays a Modal Overlay and the "Show results" button is displaying inside the `Modal overlay`

I have tried the test with `xpath` and `By.cssSelector()` way to grab the button, but still not good.

```
 WebElement showResultButton  = driverSafari.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.modal-content .app-modal-footer.modal-footer button"));
String showBtnText = driverSafari.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.modal-content .app-modal-footer.modal-footer button")).getText();
showResultButton.click();
```

// Also I have tried below to reach the button:

```
 WebElement showResultButton  = driverSafari.findElement(By.cssSelector(".modal-content>.app-modal-footer.modal-footer>button"));
```

//The xpath way is also not working:

```
 WebElement showresultButton = driverSafari.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Show results']"));
```

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.modal-content>.app-modal-footer.modal-footer>button}

```html
<div class="modal-content">
 <div class="app-modal-header modal-header"></div>
 <div class="app-modal-body modal-body"></div>
 <div class="app-modal-footer modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="primary-button  btn btn-primary btn-block">Show results</button>
 </div>
</div>
```